# Setting Object as cookie in servlet

Tags: gwt, servlets, cookies

i am using cookie to avoid rpc call i am using cookie for user authentication for the first time (when he logs in ).For that i am unable to set an User object in the servlet as cookie .because cookie constructer  allows on only string as value .

How can i set object as cookie ?
other than cookie is there any way to get the object fron HTTP session without making an RPC call ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some system for translating objects to and from JSONs. So simply translate the object into a JSON string, save it to the cookie, and translate it back into an object when you extract it from the cookie. I recommend the piriti library for handling JSONs (GWT comes with its own JSON handling library built in, but it has some limitations).

Comment: Best/easiest is to use GWT's AutoBeans. I have some sample code (in a Maven archetype) that passes a `User` object from server to client by serializing it to a JS object literal in the HTML host page: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/tree/master/guice-rf-activities/src/main/resources/archetype-resources

Comment: @ThomasBroyer am i need to change my bean structure ??

Answer (score 0):

```
if(authenticated){
                LoginPojo ch=new LoginPojo();
                ch.setImage("image");
                ch.setFullName( u.getFirst_name()+" "+u.getLast_name());
                ch.setLogin(u.getLogin);

                ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
                String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ch);
                Cookie c=new Cookie("VISITOR",jsonInString);
//              c.setSecure(true);

                response.addCookie(c);
                request.getRequestDispatcher(rootURL).forward(request, response);
}
```

But somebody says : "The HTTP State Management Mechanism specification (which deals with Cookies) states that you can't have the double quote character in the value of the cookie unless it wraps the entire thing.

Don't (try to) put JSON in cookies."